# Why standard library does not have typed accessor for `std::istream`?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std

When writing code involving reading from `std::istream` it usually disturbs me that it has to be verbose even in simple cases:

```
 int i = 0;
 std::cin >> i;
 // using your input here
```

writing a simple loop is also too verbose:

```
 int i = 0;
 for( std::cin >> i; i; --i ) { ... }
```

and it is not only verbose but forces me to extend lifetime of  `i` where it should not be. And so on.

But with rather simple addition to standard library it can be this:

```
 template <class T>
 T read( std::istream &is )
 {
      auto var = T{};
      if( !is >> var ) throw std::runtime_error( "read failed" );
      return var;
 }

 template <class T>
 T read( std::istream &is, T defValue )
 {
      is >> defValue;
      return defValue;
 }
```

(or it could be member function of `std::istream` as well). So now previous cases can be as simple as:

```
 auto i = std::read<int>( std::cin );
 // using your input here
```

or the loop:

```
 for( auto i = std::read( std::cin, 0 ); i; --i ) { ... }
```

So I think it is quite obvious that it would be useful, why it is not there?

Comment: The first thing that occurs to me is that you need to check if your read operation is successful before using the value. Your compact `for` example doesn't do that.

Comment: Generally speaking, with all library additions I guess, there are many trade offs as to how it should operate and it takes someone to spend time drawing up a proposal, taking the various trade-offs into account and presenting it to the standards committee. There is quite a queue of good ideas waiting to get in.

Comment: @Galik Good point, but it could also throw on failure (though it's not a typical thing in streams related functions)

Comment: It may be obvious to *you* that it is useful.   That doesn't mean everyone considers it useful.   As Galik points out, your usage unconditionally accesses `i` based on an assumption that the input operation always succeeds.  Good practice in handling input is to ALWAYS check that input succeeds before using the affected variable.   So you're essentially asking for the library to provide a facility that enables your poor practice.  Your chances are rather remote of convincing someone to standardise something that is known to codify poor practice.

Comment: with any file i/o (including  network  and device i/o, because they ARE files from OS perspective) it wouldn't do harm to you use "blonde's principle": chance of failure is 50% because it either would fail or it would not.

Comment: isn't `for( auto i = std::read<int>( std::cin ); i; --i ) { ... }` is the same as `std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),std::istream_iterator<int>(),[](int x){...});`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen "though it's not a typical thing in streams related functions" actually it could be https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions

Comment: @Peter we have exceptions in the language.

Comment: @Slava - So?   Exceptions are designed for (well) exceptional error conditions that are potentially irrecoverable and cannot be corrected where they are detected, whereas errors during I/O are routine occurrences, often expected and normal occurrences in a lot of programs, and generally recoverable within the code that encounters them.    There are circumstances where throwing exceptions during I/O is appropriate, but  - more often than not - they are excessive.

Comment: @Peter standard library already has that ability - to enable exceptions on reading error. So to use it or not is a choice and not bad practice. Also it is quite simple to provide a default value in case of failure. For example 0 would be safe default value as it would avoid this loop to run.

Comment: @Galik "There is quite a queue of good ideas waiting to get in." yea bureaucracy ruined many good things, looks like C++ is not going to be an exception unfortunately.

Comment: @Slava -  Throwing exceptions on I/O (stream) errors is NOT the default for a good reason - it's much less often that it is useful in practice.   Providing a default value in case of failure is problematical for types like `int`  (e.g. should the failure value be zero, a negative negative value, `INT_MIN`, `INT_MAX` or something else?    The reason that is problematical is that the choice of failure value is up to the application - whatever value was picked in the standard library would not suit every application).

Comment: @Peter default value is not problematic, I meant user provided one. So there could be `read<int>(std::cin)` wich throws exception on error, or `read<int>(std::cin, 0)` with default value which does not throw but returns user defined return value. Actually in the second you do not need to specify the type.

Comment: @Slava returning a default value won't change the fact that you need to test something to check for failure before using the returned value. You might as well just  check the stream object rather than a default value. The only way I see out of this is through *exceptions* but, as has been pointed out, *exceptions* are undesirable in a lot of cases when parsing files.

Comment: @Galik in some cases like this loop default value will work. When it does not work do not use default value. When exception do not work either do not use this method at all. Problem is currently there is no choice but use ugly obsolete multiline verbose code. I as a user of the language would use this a lot. But users do not decide what comes to standard, but bureaucracy that seem not to get any feedback what people really need.

Comment: @Slava I suppose this is why this question was judged as off-topic based on it being very much "opinion-based". As far as I can see a default value of `0` will not differentiate between an error and a genuine value `0` so it will only work in your case if the data itself is not supposed to contain a `0`. And even then you still need to explicitly check for the `0` to report (or log) the error.

Comment: @Galik you probably did not follow properly, I said default value will not be provided by this library function by itself, but would be chosen by user and passed as a parameter. So if -1 is better user would choose so. If none of them work, then do not use it. No problem. But there are a lot of cases when it does work and makes your code cleaner. Let me update the question to make it cleaner.